# How to change paragraph text onclick list item?

Tags: javascript, list, text, onclick, paragraph

I have this:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
var MessAry=new Array();
MessAry[0]='';
MessAry[1]='My Message 1';
MessAry[2]='My Message 2';
MessAry[4]='My Message 3';
MessAry[4]='My Message 4';

function CngMess(obj,id){
 document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=MessAry[obj.selectedIndex];

}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select onchange="CngMess(this,'fred');" >
<option >Select</option>
<option >Mess 1</option>
<option >Mess 2</option>
<option >Mess 3</option>
<option >Mess 4</option>
</select>
<div id="fred" ></div>
</body>
```

but I want it so that it's not a "select form" but a list (ul, li).

In other words, I want a paragraph (My Message) to change in a "fred" div when clicking on a list item.

Could somebody help?

Comment: I think he's sufficiently posted what he's tried and is working as a select element, he just isn't sure how to make it work as a ul.  All the same, I think it's appropriate how "message" is abbreviated here.

Comment: Put a click listener on the UL, use `event.target || event.srcElement` to get the element clicked on, then change the content of *Fred* appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal working version that will work in all browsers since IE/NN 4. It uses the related event object to get the element that was clicked on, gets the parent LI, then iterates over the LIs to find the index and replace the content of *Fred*.

Note that the *language* attribute for script elements is deprecated and HTML comment delimiters are not required inside script elements (and haven't been since about 1995).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var MessAry = ['', 'My Message 1', 'My Message 2','My Message 3','My Message 4'];

  function CngMess(evt, id) {
    var el = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    var ul = el.parentNode;
    var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (var i=0, iLen=lis.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      if (lis[i] == el) {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = MessAry[i];
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<ul onclick="CngMess(event, 'fred');">
  <li>Click on one of the phrases below
  <li>Mess 1
  <li>Mess 2
  <li>Mess 3
  <li>Mess 4
</ol>

<div id="fred" ></div> </body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

First, I recreated your `select` element as a `ul`:

```
<ul id="barney">
  <li>Mess 1</li>
  <li>Mess 2</li>
  <li>Mess 3</li>
  <li>Mess 4</li>
</ul>
```

Then you'll need to use event listeners instead of inline handlers.  In other words, you'll need the equivalent of `onclick`, but you want to put it in your JS, not your HTML.  There are many reasons for this, but the case here is that we'll want to use the MouseEvent object passed to the event listener.  So we'll need a cross-browser event listener to handle our events since they behave differently in different browsers:

```
function listen(evnt, elem, func) {
    if (elem.addEventListener)  // W3C DOM
        elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
    else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
         var r = elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, func);
         return r;
    }
}
```

Then we'll `listen` for a `click` event on this `ul` element.  We'll iterate over the children of the `ul` until the event target (`ev.target`), which is the `li` that was clicked, matches that child node and pass the information to a modified form of your `CngMess` function:

```
listen('click', ul, function(ev){
    for (var i = 0, il = this.children.length; i < il; i++) {
        if (ev.target == this.children[i]) {
            CngMess(this, 'fred', i);
        }
    }
});

function CngMess(obj, id, messI) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = MessAry[messI];
}​
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nrXsQ/)

Comment: That will fail in IE < 9 and other browsers that support IE's event model and not the W3C event model. You must offer support for `window.event` and `event.srcElement`.

Comment: You're right, I forgot that part.  I will re-edit when I have some time.  I forget these details now that I mostly use libraries.